# Corrective shape keys for IK-driven bone

Tags: rigging, armature, drivers, shape-keys, inverse-kinematics

The bottom bone here is affected by an IK chain:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's rotational value doesn't change unless I rotate the bone directly.

[image]

This is a problem, because I want to use it's rotational value to drive a shape key. The shape key would, if the bone is rotated, flare out the bottom part of the cylinder.

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the transforms of a bone after the actions of constraints by using a "transform channel" type variable in your driver:

[image]

Driving from a "single property" type variable won't get the post-constraint transform, just the raw f-curve values.